# É possivel adicionar icone para um programa criando em NET.core (Windows)?

Tags: c#, windows, .net-core

Tenho apenas usado os comandos de linha `dotnet`, tanto para gerar projetos, quanto gerar soluções (.sln), no entanto não sei se é possível usar `resource.rc` diretamente com `dotnet` com algo como:

```
MAINICON  ICON  "icon.ico"
```

Sendo com `resource.rc` ou outro meio gostaria de saber se isto é possivel ser feito em .net-core, ou se irei precisar de algum intermediário ou algo a mais

Comment: qual é a versão? em algum lugar eu li que ia ter isso no 3.0

Comment: @LeandroAngelo estou no 3.1 (netcoreapp3.1)

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe sim. Pra distribuir o app com ícone.

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe eu não criei sln algum, criei o csproj, mas isto é irrelevante, é o básico do básico com net-core e não net-framework, ou seja uso tudo com comando de linha `dotnet new ...` (https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new?tabs=netcore22), no meu caso `dotnet new console`, pra criar uma "aplicação console" e pra publicar `dotnet publish -c Release` (https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish?tabs=netcore21)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hoje fui efetuar um teste e aparentemente a tag funciona no `netcoreapp3.1`:

```
<ApplicationIcon>nome.ico</ApplicationIcon>
```

O projeto lógico tem que ser uma aplicação, no meu caso criei uma aplicação console:

```
mkdir projeto1
cd projeto1
dotnet new console
```

Então foi me gerado o `projeto1.csproj`, abri ele e editei desta forma:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <ApplicationIcon>nome.ico</ApplicationIcon>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Então depois executei o `dotnet run` e tanto usando as flags `-c Debug` quanto em `-c Release` (e publish também) isto funciona, o exemplo que fiz:

> [image: icone no projeto csproj para net core]

Então executei `dotnet build` e obtive o esperado:

> [image: executável com icone]